# Dynamically Load Project Data from JSON file into React

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to load a list of projects from a JSON file and display them as a list that has li's that can be selected.  The commented sections are how I was doing it before, but I want to do it without having to add a new li and a new Route every time I add a project to the JSON file.  I want to do this without JQuery.  All I have been able to find is how to parse JSON data using JQuery.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import ProjectListJS from './ProjectListJS'
import ProjectList from './ProjectList.json'
import './Projects.css'

class Projects extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="projects">
                <div className="block">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <td>
                                <ul className="list" id="spanned">
                                    {JSON.parse(ProjectList).map(function(currProject){
                                        return (
                                            <li key={currProject.id}>
                                                <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${currProject.projectName}`}>{currProject.projectName}</NavLink>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    })}
                                    {/*<li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project1.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project1.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project2.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project2.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project3.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project3.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project4.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project4.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project5.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project5.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project6.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project6.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <NavLink to={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project7.projectName}`}>{ProjectList.project7.projectName}</NavLink>
                                    </li>*/}
                                </ul>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <Switch id="spanned">
                                {JSON.parse(ProjectList).map(function(currProject){
                                    return (
                                        <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${currProject.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={currProject} /></Route>
                                    )
                                })}
                                {/*<Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project1.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project1} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project2.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project2} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project3.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project3} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project4.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project4} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project5.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project5} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project6.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project6} /></Route>
                                <Route path={`/aoppenh/projects/${ProjectList.project7.projectName}`}><ProjectListJS currentProject={ProjectList.project7} /></Route>*/}
                            </Switch>
                            </td>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Projects
```

JSON file

```
{
    "project1": {
        "id": 1,
        "projectName": "Website",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "This Website",
            "body": "My personal website craeted using the skills taught to me by Davey Strus & Seth Baughman of Fretless during Techpoint Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/aoppenh"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": "./images/website.GIF"
        }
    },

    "project2": {
        "id": 2,
        "projectName": "IRCClient",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "IRCClient",
            "body": "An irc client that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCClient"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    "project3": {
        "id": 3,
        "projectName": "IRCServer",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "IRCServer",
            "body": "An irc server that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCServer"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    "project4": {
        "id": 4,
        "projectName": "Jeffervescence",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "Jeffervescence",
            "body": "A website made during Xtern bootcamp session 2 that lists Jeff Goldblum movies, release year, and allows the user to favorite movies, reorder, delete, and clear the list",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/Jeffervescence"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    "project5": {
        "id": 5,
        "projectName": "Password Generator",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "Password Generator",
            "body": "A password generator that takes user customizations and generates a fully-random or a pseudo-random password",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/PasswordGenerator"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    "project6": {
        "id": 6,
        "projectName": "API-Party",
        "blockLeft":{
            "title": "API-Party",
            "body": "Implemented functionality using the Pokéapi v1, worked on as part of Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/api-party"
        },
        "blockRight":{
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    "project7": {
        "id": 7,
        "projectName": "2x4 Decoder",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "2x4 Decoder",
            "body": "Constructed for CS25000, on a breadboard, a 2x4 Decoder as active-low and assert when low",
            "link": null
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    }
}
```

ProjectList.js
This is the component that I am using to show the data from the projects once the Project List is displayed in Project.js.  This component works when I use the comment parts to load the project list, but my problem is loading the list dynamically instead, but in case you want to see how the whole thing works if it changes your answer.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ProjectList from './ProjectList.json'

class ProjectListJS extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            currentProject: props.currentProject,
            projects: ProjectList,
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ currentProject: nextProps.currentProject })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span className="block-left" id="div">
                    <div className="block-top">
                        {(this.state.currentProject === null) ? null : this.state.currentProject.blockLeft.title}
                    </div>
                    <div className="block-bottom">
                        {(this.state.currentProject === null) ? null : this.state.currentProject.blockLeft.body}
                    </div>
                    <a href={(this.state.currentProject === null) ? null : this.state.currentProject.blockLeft.link} target="_blank" className="link">
                        {(this.state.currentProject === null) ? null : this.state.currentProject.blockLeft.link}
                    </a>
                </span>
                <span className="block-right" id="div">
                    <img id="tech" src={`${(this.state.currentProject === null) ? null : this.state.currentProject.blockRight.img}`} alt="img" />
                </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ProjectListJS
```

Comment: JSON.parse is javascript and not jquery !

Comment: yeah, but I can't seem to get this to work

Comment: what I want to do is what I did by adding a new li and route for each project, but I want to do it dynamically.

Comment: @aoppenh, would you please put the `ProjectListJS.js` file here.

Comment: Change `JSON.parse(ProjectList)` to just `ProjectList` everywhere. `import ProjectList from './ProjectList.json'` will import that file and it will already be object - no need to parse.

Comment: I get this error when I do that,    TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ProjectList_json___default.a.map is not a function

Comment: Check my answer for fix that problem.

Comment: Your JSON file is not an `Array` - it is an `Object` because it begin from `{`. An  `Object` does not have `map()` method. Rewrite it to `Array`.

Comment: Replace `JSON.parse(ProjectList).map` to `Object.keys(ProjectList).map(function(key){ return ... ProjectList[key] ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change JSON.parse(ProjectList) to just ProjectList everywhere. import ProjectList from './ProjectList.json'

Then change `ProjectList.map`

to

`ProjectList.forEach`

Then change `./ProjectList.json`

as follows:-

```
[
  {
        "id": 1,
        "projectName": "Website",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "This Website",
            "body": "My personal website craeted using the skills taught to me by Davey Strus & Seth Baughman of Fretless during Techpoint Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/aoppenh"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": "./images/website.GIF"
        }
    },

     {
        "id": 2,
        "projectName": "IRCClient",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "IRCClient",
            "body": "An irc client that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCClient"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

     {
        "id": 3,
        "projectName": "IRCServer",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "IRCServer",
            "body": "An irc server that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCServer"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

   {
        "id": 4,
        "projectName": "Jeffervescence",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "Jeffervescence",
            "body": "A website made during Xtern bootcamp session 2 that lists Jeff Goldblum movies, release year, and allows the user to favorite movies, reorder, delete, and clear the list",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/Jeffervescence"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

    {
        "id": 5,
        "projectName": "Password Generator",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "Password Generator",
            "body": "A password generator that takes user customizations and generates a fully-random or a pseudo-random password",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/PasswordGenerator"
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    },

     {
        "id": 6,
        "projectName": "API-Party",
        "blockLeft":{
            "title": "API-Party",
            "body": "Implemented functionality using the Pokéapi v1, worked on as part of Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
            "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/api-party"
        },
        "blockRight":{
            "img": ""
        }
    },

     {
        "id": 7,
        "projectName": "2x4 Decoder",
        "blockLeft": {
            "title": "2x4 Decoder",
            "body": "Constructed for CS25000, on a breadboard, a 2x4 Decoder as active-low and assert when low",
            "link": null
        },
        "blockRight": {
            "img": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have them as an array of objects, import them in your component and then loop through them. Rendering each item as a list item like so.

> import them in your component

```
import { Projects } from './Projects'
const projects = Projects


{ projects.map((project, i) => <Component i={i} key={i} project={project} />) }
```

> JSON file

```
export const Projects  =
     [ "project1": {
            "id": 1,
            "projectName": "Website",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "This Website",
                "body": "My personal website craeted using the skills taught to me by Davey Strus & Seth Baughman of Fretless during Techpoint Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/aoppenh"
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": "./images/website.GIF"
            }
        },

        "project2": {
            "id": 2,
            "projectName": "IRCClient",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "IRCClient",
                "body": "An irc client that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCClient"
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": ""
            }
        },

        "project3": {
            "id": 3,
            "projectName": "IRCServer",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "IRCServer",
                "body": "An irc server that works over local host created as a project at Purdue University in cs24000 - Programming in C",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/IRCServer"
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": ""
            }
        },

        "project4": {
            "id": 4,
            "projectName": "Jeffervescence",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "Jeffervescence",
                "body": "A website made during Xtern bootcamp session 2 that lists Jeff Goldblum movies, release year, and allows the user to favorite movies, reorder, delete, and clear the list",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/Jeffervescence"
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": ""
            }
        },

        "project5": {
            "id": 5,
            "projectName": "Password Generator",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "Password Generator",
                "body": "A password generator that takes user customizations and generates a fully-random or a pseudo-random password",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/PasswordGenerator"
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": ""
            }
        },

        "project6": {
            "id": 6,
            "projectName": "API-Party",
            "blockLeft":{
                "title": "API-Party",
                "body": "Implemented functionality using the Pokéapi v1, worked on as part of Xtern-Bootcamp 2017 session 2",
                "link": "https://github.com/aoppenh/api-party"
            },
            "blockRight":{
                "img": ""
            }
        },

        "project7": {
            "id": 7,
            "projectName": "2x4 Decoder",
            "blockLeft": {
                "title": "2x4 Decoder",
                "body": "Constructed for CS25000, on a breadboard, a 2x4 Decoder as active-low and assert when low",
                "link": null
            },
            "blockRight": {
                "img": ""
            }
        }
    ]
```